# Why would I get an Invalid or unqualified reference part way through an AppointItem?

Tags: excel, vba, appointment

The code stops running with .Body = "" highlighted and says it is an invalid or unqualified
reference.  Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Note that the variables that start with Appt_ are all global variables defined in another module.

```
Sub RegisterAppointmentList(CName As String)

' adds a list of appontments to the Calendar in Outlook
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Set olAppItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

On Error Resume Next

Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If olApp Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Outlook is not available!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If


olAppItem _
    .Location = ""
    .Body = ""
    .Start = Nothing
    .End = Nothing
    .ReminderSet = True
    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
    .BusyStatus = olFree
    .RequiredAttendees = "jerry@1sba.com"
     On Error Resume Next
    .Start = Appt_STime
    .End = Appt_ETime
    .Subject = CName & "," & Appt_Subject
    .Location = Appt_Location
    .Body = Appt_Description
    .ReminderSet = True
    .BusyStatus = olBusy
     On Error GoTo 0
    .Save ' saves the new appointment to the default folder

Set olAppItem = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
MsgBox "Done !"
End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing a `with` and `end with` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change multiple properties, the best way to do it would be using "With":

```
With olAppItem
    .Location = ""
    .Body = ""
    .Start = Nothing
    .End = Nothing
    .ReminderSet = True
    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
    .BusyStatus = olFree
    .RequiredAttendees = "jerry@1sba.com"
     On Error Resume Next
    .Start = Appt_STime
    .End = Appt_ETime
    .Subject = CName & "," & Appt_Subject
    .Location = Appt_Location
    .Body = Appt_Description
    .ReminderSet = True
    .BusyStatus = olBusy
     On Error GoTo 0
    .Save ' saves the new appointment to the default folder
End With
```

Comment: That helped a lot.   Now it says that the 
"Set olAppItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)" doesn't support this property or method.  It looks exactly like multiple examples of code on the net.  Any ideas or should i post another question?

Comment: I suppose (since there's a "excel" tag) that you're trying to run this code from Excel VBA, is that right? Application.CreateItem is a Method available on Outlook (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitem), but when you run it from Excel, Application refers to Excel. Maybe you should reference the Outlook Application object olApp (Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)), or try to run the example in Outlook VBA.